# How to implement custom Keras regulizer with output of another model as a parameter?

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, keras, loss-function

I'm trying to replicate this article: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1705.08302.pdf

Basically, a fully convolutional network (FCN) does voxel level predictions on a patch of a image, then, this patch and its respective labels are passed through an autoencoder and then compared to evaluate the "global shape" of the predictions.

So the loss function (eq. (1) page 4) is a linear combination between the cross entropy from the FCN and euclidean distance loss from the autoencoder.

**Problem:**

I have a working FCN and a working autoencoder, my problem has been implementing this loss function in Keras/tensorflow. So, how can I do that?

This is what I tried so far (without third term of equation) but gives wrong results:

```
def euclidean_distance_loss(y_true, y_pred):
    from keras import backend as K
return K.sqrt(K.sum(K.square(y_pred - y_true)))

def ACNN_loss(l1, autoencoder):
    from keras import backend as K

    def loss(y_true, y_pred):
        ae_seg = autoencoder(y_pred)
        ae_gt = autoencoder(y_true)

        Lhe = K.sqrt(K.sum(K.square(ae_seg - ae_gt)))

        Lx = K.binary_crossentropy(y_true, y_pred)

        return Lx + (l1 * Lhe)

return loss

l1 = 0.01

ae_path = #path of my autoencoder model and its weights
autoencoder = keras.models.load_model(os.path.join(ae_path,'model.h5'), custom_objects={'euclidean_distance_loss': euclidean_distance_loss})

autoencoder.load_weights(os.path.join(ae_path,'weigths.h5'))


model.compile(loss = ACNN_loss(l1, autoencoder),
              optimizer = keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=0.0003, beta_1=0.9, beta_2=0.999, epsilon=1e-08, decay=0.0),
              metrics= ['accuracy', keras.metrics.binary_crossentropy]
              )
```

This is my first question so sorry if I messed up on any requirements. Thanks in advance

Comment: what result are you expecting? The heading should be a question so that we understand what you want specifically

Comment: Thank you for the tip.I want to improve my FCN predictions by using the information of the autoencoder loss. My question is how to implement a regulizer in keras using the output of another model as a parameter

Comment: Please [edit] your post to include any additional information you have to your question. Avoid adding this in the comments, as they are harder to read and can be deleted easier. The edit button for your post is just below the post's tags.

Answer (score -1):

The square-**root** is unnecessary. Looking on the paper you attached, the loss doesn't contains a sqrt function. I.e. the regularization term takes the squared-distance, instead of the norm-distance

Specifically, you should replace

```
Lhe = K.sqrt(K.sum(K.square(ae_seg - ae_gt)))
```

with

```
Lhe = K.sum(K.square(ae_seg - ae_gt))
```

In general, L2 regularization always takes the squared distance.

Comment: Are you talking about the euclidean_distance_loss?
I thought the euclidean norm was calculated as I did, from what I saw on wikipedia

Comment: I refer to `Lhe = K.sqrt(K.sum(K.square(ae_seg - ae_gt)))`. In general, calculating distance is indeed as what you did, but thats not how the loss is calculated. Also, see Eq 4. on the paper. They don't take a sqrt.

Comment: @jfga, great :)
PS: If you found my answer helpful, please up-vote or accept it